# fopen Creates File, But how to change permissions?

Tags: php, file-permissions, fopen, chmod, chown

I am creating a new file using fopen.

```
$filename = 'user_data/10.xml';
$openhandle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
```

Then I check if the file has been created using: `file_exists()` function.

The problem is: The file is being created with some owner, probably the folder name, but its not me. Also the permissions of the file is only `readable  by the owner`.
And since I am not the owner, I can't read the file, or change the permissions.

But If attempt to change it using:

```
chown($filename, 'myusername');
chmod($filename, 777);
```

I tried changing the file owner and permissions using the Terminal using `sudo`. That worked properly.
So I also tried using the functions above with `shell_exec()` so it runs in root.

But had no luck.

Although, I don't have much experience with file permission numbers, the chown command is also not working.

So how should I change the owner and permissions of the file so i'm the owner and its readable and writable by my other PHP scripts?

Comment: When the file is uploaded (before any chmod), what are the permissions on the file, what are the permissions on user_data folder, and who is the assigned owner?

Comment: I create a new empty file, and then write to it using fwrite(). The permissions on the file are:
Owner and Group: www-data
Owner: read
Group: execute
Others: execute

On the user_data folder, I'm the owner and all the three people are set to Read, Write, Execute...

Comment: As TimWickstrong says, you should add a leading 0 to the chmod command, but it also occurs that you may not have permission to chmod. Try $chmoded = chmod($filename,0777); if (!$chmoded){echo "Could not change the file permissions";}... also, if the file permissions are 777 there is no need to chown.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to chmod it using only the following line:

```
chmod($filename, 0777);
```

Note the 0 before the 777.

Also do not change the ownership before it has been chmod'ed